# How to calculate the sum of combinatorial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation

For my work on an almost completely unrelated field I came across the following formula. I know that I have learned that all in high school. But since this is more than 15 years ago in which I never used this kind of mathematics I now realize that I am completely lost...

So I have the following formula:

$$\sum_{A=42}^{200} \binom{A-1}{A-42} \times 6^{42}$$

I know the first step to calculate this is the following:

$$\sum_{A=42}^{200} \frac{(A-1)!}{(A-42)! \times ((A-1)-(A-42))!} \times 6^{42}$$

Now I need the solution to this formula in terms of $10^x$, so basically the $x$ value. What I am interested in is of course also the steps of this calculation, to understand how this is done.

Comment: To the extent of crunching it out, there's not much to be said at a mathematical level: Compute factorials and large powers, take ratios, add together, etc...a tremendous calculation, and one you'd be well advised to do on a computer if at all. (I say 'at all' because this is the sort of thing where you'd be much better served either settling for an approximation or finding an easier expression for the same number.)

Comment: First of all, just pull the $6^{42}$ out of the expression.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Now I need the solution to this formula in terms of $10^x$, so basically the $x$ value."? Are you asking for an order of magnitude estimate?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes exactly, how to I approximate/estimate the $x$ value of $10^x$?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something known as the [Hockeystick Identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity#Hockey-Stick_Identity):

$\displaystyle\sum_{A = 42}^{200}\dbinom{A-1}{A-42} = \sum_{A = 42}^{200}\dbinom{A-1}{41} = \sum_{n = 41}^{199}\dbinom{n}{41} = \dbinom{199+1}{41+1} = \dbinom{200}{42}$.

Now, multiply both sides by $6^{42}$.

Using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28200%20choose%2042%29*6%5E42), we get that $\dbinom{200}{42}6^{42} \approx 1.46 \times 10^{76}$. If you wanted to evaluate this by hand, you can write the sum as $\dfrac{200! \cdot 6^{42}}{158! \cdot 42!}$ and then use [Sterling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: That seems to be a nice solution. Thanks also for the link to WolframAlpha.